# pytesseract img to string conversion not working

Tags: python, ocr, tesseract, python-tesseract

[image: Here is the image i want to convert to string]

I have this image and my code to convert it to string is:

```
import pytesseract 
from PIL import Image

print(pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open("screenshot.png")))
```

and my ouptut is nothing...

any suggestion?

Comment: Please read and follow tesseract documentation.

Answer (score 0):

The string conversion of an image might be very long... Depending on your editor, it may hide it

Comment: I'm using VS code, how do i know if it is hiding it?